# Закрытие элемента (выпадающий список с совпадениями) при клике за его пределами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Список появляется под строкой поиска на сайте при вводе: java, asp, php, если есть совпадения. Но если мы ничего не выбрали, то список не закрывается. Нужно чтобы при клике вне этого списка, он закрывался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]http://stomfl8t.beget.tech/

Как можно реализовать данную задачу, использую [этот](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Tagging-System-Autocomplete-Amsify-Suggestags.html) виджет?

Comment: Сделайте проверку на введение для `input`, если там есть что-то, то для вашего листа делайте `display: flex;`, иначе скрывайте...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
   var selectList = $(".amsify-suggestags-list");
   var selectWrap = $('.amsify-suggestags-input-area');
   if (selectWrap.has(e.target).length === 0 && selectList.has(e.target).length === 0 && !selectWrap.hasClass('.amsify-focus')){
      selectList.addClass('hide-element');
   } else {
      selectList.removeClass('hide-element');
   }
});
```

Comment: я сделал так, <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).mouseup(function (e){
  var div = $("#close");
  if (!div.is(e.target)
  && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
  div.hide();
  }
 });
});
</script>
работает, но на смартфоне не работает вот http://stomfl8t.beget.tech/, как можно это исправить? что бы работало и на смартфоне скрытие списка после клика в любом месте экрана

Comment: Вместо mouseup, click написать. Мышки же нету на телефонах.

Comment: Отметьте ответ как правильный если он вам подошёл.

Comment: а потом на компьютере будет работать?

Comment: Ну так проверьте

Comment: спасибо вам за ваши ответы, проверил http://stomfl8t.beget.tech/ на компе работает, а вот в телефоне попрежнему нет

Comment: все заработало, спасибо!!!

Comment: Отлично, рад за вас!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var elementid = $('#elementid');
    elementid.mouseover(function () {
        alert(':)');
    });
});
```